# Android action bar overflow

Tags: android

I was reading [this article](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Android-Action-Bar-from-the-Options-Menu.aspx), and was surprised to read that:

> You might notice only 2 of the 3 original menu items are displayed in
>   the new action bar [...].  To get the other menu items, you must go to
>   the "overflow menu".

The reason why I'm surprised is that when I do the same thing using an emulated Nexus (ie: no menu button) running on Android 4.1.2, then the overflow button does not appear [in the menu](http://www.intertech.com/PostingImages/Android-Action-Bar-from-the-Options-Menu_E1C5/image_thumb_7.png), but directly [in the action bar](http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-stacked.png).

Any idea why the behavior is different ?

**Note**: in my AndroidManifest.xml, I'm using minSdkVersion="11"

Answer (score 2):

The button which appears in the naviagation bar for devices which lack physical buttons isn't the overflow button; it's the legacy menu button. The behavior you are seeing is the correct, expected behavior.

Comment: In that case, how is it possible to combine an action bar with a legacy menu button ? My understanding was that the action bar was supposed to replace the legacy menu button... so I don't understand how the author of the article managed to combine both.

Comment: The legacy menu button appears when your app's minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion are set to < 11. The action bar is supposed to replace the legacy menu button. To get the screenshot of both, it looks like the author added an action bar and set the api level to 10.

Comment: ... except that the author says that he set the minSdk value to 11: "If you were to simply change the minimum version of the SDK to be 11..."